# `pkill` and static objects destruction in C++

Tags: c++, static, pkill

There is a C++ structure having static instance:

```
class A
{
public:
   A () {}
   
   ~A() {
       // smth.
   }
} a;
```

Does `pkill` of process calls destructors of all static objects implemented in C++?
Is there a guarentee that `pkill`, before process termination will call destructor of `a`?

Comment: Killing a process terminates it immediately, which pretty much guarantees that the process does not get the opportunity to do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

`pkill`, like `kill`, sends a signal to the process.  By default it sends `SIGTERM`, but it can send any signal you tell it to.

The default handler for `SIGTERM` terminates the process immediately, without running object destructors or functions registered with `atexit`.  You can change this behavior by registering your own signal handler using the [`signal`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) or [`sigaction`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) functions.  If you want to let the rest of your program clean up gracefully, you can have a `std::atomic<bool>` that the rest of your program periodically checks to determine if it should continue working.

Note that you are fairly limited in what you can safely do in a signal handler.  Linux, for example, has a list of [async-signal-safe functions](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) that you can safely call.  C++17 also specifically specifies that member functions of `std::atomic` types are safe if the type is lock-free.  That means that you should *not* simply call `std::exit` directly from a signal handler, since that will execute objects' destructors in the context of the signal handler, which will likely perform unsafe operations.